# How can I find out the actual rpms my dc motor at any given moment?

Tags: dc-motor

In my next project it will be very helpful to monitor the speed of my dc motor. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the cornucopia of methods that burst forth from Russell's answer you could consider to add yet another to that rich bounty- if you have sufficient off time in your maximum PWM duty cycle you may be able to harness the back EMF of the motor itself as a tachometer signal. This has the advantage of being sensorless. It can be a suitable method for motors that are permanent magnet or that have a separate field winding. There must be sufficient time for the energy stored in the rotor inductance to die down, after which you can simply sample the voltage with an ADC.

A detailed description of this method can be found [here.](http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes-technical-guides/application-bulletins/ab-021-measuring-rpm-from-back-emf) The back EMF is proportional to the RPM of the motor, and of the same polarity as the applied voltage (assuming a PM type or fixed field voltage) when measured at the terminals.

Comment: This looks to be a little above my head but I love that it's an "out of the box" approach. I'll definitely give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possible ways that the best way depends on the details.
Some suggestions

Pulse per revolution from mechanical or magnetic or optical switch or ... .
Triggers could be "cam or bump", magnet, slot or mark or light or ... .

Or several pulses per revolution using either multiple sensors or multiple triggers.
Extending to ...

Tachometer track - series of marks or slots or magnetically variable permeability disk or ...

Small alternator/generator attached to shaft (often known as a tachometer).

---

Once you have one or multiple pulses per revolution you can

- count the number over a given period, or
- measure the time between them, or
- trigger a fixed length pulse per input pulse (known as a retriggerable monostable) so that the mean DC level out is a measure of speed.
- or ....

---

Where the output is a period you need to take the reciprocal to get speed. A basic microcontroller such as an Arduino can do this easily. THese can be obtained for as little as [$US2.85 each](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Freeshipping-10PCS-LOT-Nano-3-0-controller-compatible-with-arduino-nano-NO-CABLE/213957_1511622386.html) if you buy 10 or [$US4.50 each](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Freeshipping-Nano-3-0-controller-compatible-with-arduino-nano-NO-CABLE/213957_1511600580.html) if you buy one.
Get a few friends to buy one too and get 10! [No, I have no relationship with them except as a happy customer]